# project dependencies and NuGet shows warnings

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nuget-package

I am trying to run a project.but it shows warning among project.The error list appear like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umXcB.png)

Solution Explorer shows this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWMU0.png)

I tried ,
deleting bin folders and rerun the project.
restore the NuGet package.
Added these to app config

But still it is not ok.help me to fix.I am new to asp.net.

Comment: what is the target .net framework version of your project? Also, what is the targetFramework in packages.config file? I believe this is mostly related to versioning, or you are referring to older version of the nuget packages.

Comment: my .net framework is 4.6.1 and nuget packages also updated.i will see more.thank you very much.